Does all storage medias have a unique volume label set by default?
I have a task to figure out how to get volume labels out of certain medias,
so that I can use it as a key to differentiate each medias that I have.
After doing some research, for example if I have a E: drive I can just use the command

vol E:

to retrieve the volume label.
However when I try it on some other medias (in my case XDCAM), it shows like below

Volume in drive D: is XDCAM 
Volume Serial Number is FFFF-FFFF

which indicates that it doesn't have a unique volume label.
I always thought that all storage medias would have a unique volume label set by default but is it not necessarily the case?
If not then what other options can i go for to get a unique identifier key for each of the storage medias that I am working on?

Volume Labels are entirely optional, and are designed to be user-configured at the time of formatting. there are unique identifiers like linux UUIDs, but the volume label is not one of these. you can even have multiple volumes with the same label on the same system at the same time.

@Frank Thank you for your explanation!
Is there any way to obtain the linux UUID when Im using windows?

these are all properties of the filesystem and/or the partition table on the disk. see here for some relevant discussion: https://serverfault.com/questions/545976/ntfs-volume-guid

Thank you! I'll go check the link out!

As a further note, not all operating systems support volume labels.
